# AngularJS - Overlay admin layout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm here for a little question about angularJS...
Currently at work we are working on an app that need an "overlay" admin style panel.

Lets take this exemple :

http://olivierbossel.com/others/angularJS-overlay.jpg

In the first part, the url is "myapp.com/#/works". To display this I have currently configured my $routeProvider.when('/works', { templateUrl: ... etc... And I have in my template the ng-view directive that handle the load and the display of the template. Ok for this part...

My question is : 
How to display a content in another part of the page like in the second part of the picture where the url is "myapp.com/#/admin" ?
In this case, the admin template has to be displayed in an overlay style element...

Hope somebody has an answer for me, that will be extremely helpfull...

Thanks in advance !

See you !
Best regard
Olivier

Comment: would [ng:show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) or [ng:hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide) not work in the dashboard overlay template you're loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-modal.  It basically shows/hides the modal depending on an ng-model variable.

**Edit**: Here's an example doing what you want:  Open a modal on the same page depending on the routeParams: http://plnkr.co/edit/DOPmBT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite what I want but the problem is that this is just a modal and this is not linked to the url..
What I want to create is that when the url is .../#/admin/something, the admin panel shows up and the "something" view display in the overlay. I don't understand why angularJS don't have the possibility to configure multiple $routeProvider linked to different ngview or something like that... an idea ?

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example doing what you want.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. That help me for a part of the solution.
I'm now in front of another issue.. With my location "/admin/myPage" I load the admin layout that contain an <div ng-include="myTemplate">. This load is made by a jquery ajax request and so my injected admin layout isn't inited by angular and my ng-include directive isn't resolved. How can I execute angularJS on an jquery injected content?
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: I guess I've find a solution with the $compile service to apply angularJS on my jquery ajax loaded content... Thanks for your time and answers :)